# How do you get an Xcode bot into Xcode.app if it was created in a browser?

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

I created an Xcode bot via the browser, but it doesn't show up in my Xcode.app. I found instructions to create the bot via Xcode.app, which seems to work. But why doesn't my existing browser-created bot show up in Xcode.app?

*Server 13S4138, OS X 10.9.2 (Build 13C64), Xcode 5.1 (5B130a)*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I fixed it by going into preferences on my development machine.

If you look in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and add a new server on the left panel. Then restart Xcode just to be safe and after a small delay all the related bots on your server should appear in the log navigator.